# Rails: HTML gets displayed as plain text

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, plaintext

***After we had performed an upgrade of Rails***, we have noticed an issue (or rather a weird behavior) with our application. Specifically, the upgrade from Rails 3 to newer version 4.

The scenario is as follows:

> In time to time, when we access the web page, **the very first request** ends up with page loaded, however ***HTML is rendered as a plain text*** (the top part of the figure). After I press F5, the page loads correctly (the bottom part of the figure) and so it does subsequent times (you may see it in the figure below), simply works as expected.

[image: App]

This behavior I consider completely random as there is not deterministic time or situation I can clearly predict it to happen again:

- it *sometimes* happens, when I access the page after longer period of time (a day or two)
- <strike>it does not happen at all in rare cases (we have carried out tests on various browsers and machines)</strike>

Wish I could provide more information on the matter. However, I feel lost at the moment and have no idea, what kind of other relevant application details would be beneficial to resolve the problem.

Either your thoughts or suggestions would be more than appreciated. Thank you.

**Edit:**

Well, it seems like the behavior takes place once we run the application in the ***production environment***. Additionally, the statement above regarding occurrence of the issue is no more true as ***it happens on any browser and any machine*** at the time.

Comment: May you add you `application_layout` head section, controller and view? Also `Gemfile` may be useful too.